# Closed ideal in $ L^{1}(G)$

Tags: banach-spaces, ideals

Let $G$ be locally compact group prove that

> $$L_{0}^{1}(G)=\left\{f\in L^{1}(G): \int_G f(g) dm(g)=0 \right\}$$
>   is a closed ideal in  $  L^{1}(G)$ with codimension one

I am grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $f,g\in L^1(G)$ it's easy to verify from the definition that $$\int_Gf*g=\int_G f\int_Gg.$$

Comment: @Dear David C. Ullrich, thanks, could you tell me how to do I prove closed?

Comment: @user62498 Come on  now! Say $I$ is that set. It should be obvious that $I$ is the kernel of a bounded linear functional. Or if that's too abstract, assume $f_n\in I$, $f_n\to  f$  and show $f\in I$.

Comment: thanks,  your comment is definitely an improvement over mine I do it